# set metadata for an audio stream in external music player

Tags: android, stream, media-player, uri, soundcloud

unfortunately I'm unable to set metadata such as "TITLE" or "ARTIST" for a track which I'm streaming from soundcloud in an external musicplayer.

This is how I thought it should work:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/135150341/stream?client_id=MY_SECRET_CLIENT_ID");
    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM, "BLA");
    it.putExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "TEST TITLE");
    it.putExtra(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "TEST ARTIST");
    it.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/mp3");
    startActivity(it);
```

After this part I can choose my favorite player and it'll start playing the track, 
but I cannot set the metada... I don't see any name of the artist or the track or anything...

Is there any way to set the metadata for this audio stream?
Or to get the metadata from soundcloud directly?

Thanks in advance,
Marcus

Comment: The keys you're using, `MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM`, etc, aren't necessarily used by the apps you're trying to play music from. You would have to figure out exactly which keys to use for each specific player.

Comment: How can I figure it out?
If I would know which keys the top 3 media players are using, then I could send all of them via intent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the streamed mp3 file does not have the metadata.

You can access all data available using following api call:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/135150341.json?client_id=10fe52a882bf103b82641c33870f6500
```

Comment: I've checked the json object directly via online json parser:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/135150341.json?client_id=10fe52a882bf103b82641c33870f6500

Anyway I still have the problem that the player didn't get any information about the track, because I don't know how to set it.